# JS sandbox iframe no external resources

Tags: javascript, html, sandbox

I would like to show email content on a webApp but would like to prevent js execution and loading resources that are not embedded(base64). Is there a feature that can disable such things on an iframe or some thing like that? Or do i need to parse and remove unwanted data by myself (Really not my favorit thing to do and will be a hard to keep it working properly.)?

To prevent JS execution i can use the sandbox attribute:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox

But i don't know how i can prevent access to external resources (Images, Audio, CSS, ...) in an easy way. I could parse and modify the content but that sounds like a good way to mess up the security aspect of my goal ^^.

Comment: I think parsing it yourself would be simple enough. You just need to iterate through the constructed DOM and remove the elements whose attributes you don't like.

Comment: Ok i hoped there would be a out of the box solution for this. But if there is none guess i will go for it.